# How to create a menu with keyboard control in the windows terminal

Tags: python, windows, terminal, menu, keyboard

You need to create a class that displays a menu in the Windows terminal, with the ability to select using arrows on the keyboard, and when you press the enter key, the selected element is returned

I tried using the simple_term_menu module. But on my computer running the windows operating system, the module does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the project's description on pypy](https://pypi.org/project/simple-term-menu/):

> Currently, Linux and macOS are supported.

You may want to try using another library, such as [textual](https://github.com/Textualize/textual), or one of many others. Have a search for the keywords "python terminal user interface".